# Find the number of degree 1 vertices in terms of n and d

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees, eulerian-path

Fix an integer $d>1$. Let $G$ be a tree with $n$ vertices, and every vertex can have either degree $1$ or $d$. Find the number of degree $1$ vertices in terms of $d$ and $n$. 
I've been working on this problem and I feel like I almost have the answer. I worked out that if $d=2$, the graph will just be a line with vertices and $2$ leaves, so there will be $2$ vertices with $\deg(1)$, no matter how many vertices there actually are. If $d=3$, $n$ starts to matter.

Using the fact that the sum of all the $\deg(v)$ of a graph is $2|E|$ and that in a tree $|E|=|V|-1$ I worked out that the sum of $\deg(v)=2n-1$, and that this sum mod $d$ will be the amount of degree $1$ vertices. ( Since $d+d+d+\dots+1+1+1+1$ mod $d$ will be the sum of the $1$'s unless the sum is greater than $d$, then it will wrap around). I'm having a hard time putting this all together into a simple equation. I don't want just the solution, I want to understand how to find the equation as well.

Comment: Any reason for rolling back the edits?

Comment: @PJK it was accidental, I set it back to the first edit.

Comment: Ah I see. Its okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n_1$ be the number of degree $1$ vertices, and $n_d$ the number of degree $d$ vertices.

Then (the first two lines are the facts as you have already noted):
$$
|E| = \frac12 \sum \mbox{ deg } v_i = \frac12 ( n_1 + d n_d ) \\
|E| = |v| - 1 = (n_1 + n_d) -1 \\
\frac12 ( n_1 + d n_d ) = (n_1 + n_d) -1 \\
n_1 + n_d = n \implies n_d = n - n_1\\
\frac12 ( n_1 + d (n-n_1) ) = n - 1 \\
 n_1 + d (n-n_1)  = 2(n - 1) \\
n_1(1-d) + nd = 2n - 2 \\
n_1 = \frac{(2-d) n - 2}{1-d} = n + \frac{n-2}{d-1}
$$

Comment: **Note:** With your last line, $\frac{(2−d)n−2}{1−d}=\frac{(1−d)n+n−2}{1−d}=n+\frac{n−2}{1−d}$. As such, you should either change the + between the $2$ terms to − or change the second term's denominator to $1−d$. For what it's worth, I think the former is better than the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say there are $p$ number of degree $1$ vertices. Then sum of the degree of the vertices is $p+d(n-p)$ which is equal to $2(n-1)$ i.e. twice the number of edges of an $n$ vertex tree. This gives the number $p$.